# Plenum in air intake system of automobiles

Tags: transmission, radiator, carburetor, mechanics-trade

What is a plenum? What role does it play in the air intake system of cars?Do naturally aspirated engines use plenum?

Comment: Plenum is a new name for Intake Manifold.

Comment: I'd recommend watching this video, which provides a detailed overview of the engineering behind intake manifolds.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMjAtDGdWRM

Answer (score 1):

The plenum is usually an enlarged section feeding the 4, 5, 6, 8 or more ports so that there is less turbulence in the air as it enters the ports.

Too much turbulence and funny things start to happen like one cylinder runs rich compared to the others.

Comment: What is the pressure inside plenum? Is it greater than the atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Non turbo lower than atmos, turbo above atmos... but now you are just adding questions. If my answer helped then you should at least give it a vote.